# Is there any mapping of $N^3$ unique values to $N \times N \times N$ dots which underlie associative function(s) to next and prior dot, cyclic (SxSxS)

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, cyclic-groups, cryptography, permutation-cycles

Title in long:
Is there any mapping of $N^3$ unique values to $N \times N \times N$ elements which underlie associative function(s)/operator to next and previous element (and no more) for each dimension in a cyclic arrangement ($\mathbb{S^1}\times\mathbb{S^1}\times\mathbb{S^1}$)?

### Problem by example

For a computer program I'm looking for some sort of three-dimensional matrix ($N \times N \times N$) with random elements. This matrix need to be bigger than storage allows but equal for each user (with same conditions).
To accomplish this the matrix elements should start at a random entry and compute the matrix out of this (using constants/functions/operators).
Each dimension has $N$ element but no start or end. Arrangement is cyclic like a 3-dimensional torus $\mathbb{S}\times\mathbb{S}\times\mathbb{S}$.

Every user has (in general) a different initial value. He should not know how to compute another user value out of his own.
The matrix is big but not big enough for common cryptographic methods like elliptic curves.
So to achieve this property only a function/operator for next and previous element is allowed (for each dimension). Computing e.g. the 2nd next requires the knowledge of the next.

So the computation complexity/time need to scale (about) linear with shift (next->1, 2nd next->2 times 'next',..., n'th next->n times computation time of 'next').
Furthermore complexity/time need to be (about) equal for each dimension.

### Some more properties

-next of previous element is the element itself again
-independent of dimension order calculation (associative)
-after $N$ times 'next' the same element again (cyclic)
-there need to be some way to produce a (pseudo) random element without deriving the position in this matrix
-need to work at a computer

### Weakening

(options to make problem less demanding)
-cycle size don't need to be $N$ in each dimension. Sizes can be different to each other but need to be close to a certain value of choice
-instead of just next/previous also some shortcuts for constant shifts are allowed (number $\ll N$), e.g. $N$'th next-> same again, $N$/2'th next -> ...
-shortcuts for each shift can be allowed if computation time much langer than for elliptic curves 
-matrix elements don't need to be unique in matrix. Small amount of multiple usage of same value can be allowed
-values don't need to be in range of $[0,...,N^3]$, not all vales in range need to be part of it
-instead of equal matrices for every user also multiple which are different to each other are allowed (but total number need to be smaller than $2N$)

### What doesn't work

-split in a value for each dimension (unless each of those is different after next/previous function). Finding another value would reduce of finding a equal value for each dimension. Target matrix size of one dimension ($N$) too small for this. Unless next/previous function need long computation time. Furthermore there should be no (effective) way to reduce an element to an index of each dimension.
-elliptic curve encryption and other methods which need more bit (at least those I know off)

---

Any ideas which might work? Problem has many properties but solution can be part of different topics. Mathematics not my major. Name of topics where this problem fit in also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) in each direction.  In one dimension, if the current value is $n$ the next value is $an+c \pmod m$.  You choose $a,c$ for each direction and use a common $m$.  If $a$ is coprime to $m$ this is invertible, so you can go backwards as well.  It will be cyclic with period shorter than $m$.  If you choose $a,c$ properly I think you can get $m-1$ so you have the same period in all three axes.  All the values will be smaller than $m$, which means there will be many repeats, but maybe that is not a problem.  I think getting it cyclic and keeping the values distinct is difficult.  Also if the user has access to the numbers in the matrix he can derive $a,c,m$ with some work.  Is that a problem?  You could use some other seeded random number generator.  This one came to mind because you could go backwards easily.

Comment: ty for response. This approach splits the problem into one for each dimension. If a user want to compute another users value out of his own he only need to compute each dimension by itself. My wished target size is too small for this (written in 'what doesn't work' section). A PC could do that in some hours. For $N^3$ elements instead more than $10^{15}$ years needed.

Comment: many repeats not a problem unless this happen across dimensions. If elements calculated for each dimension over and over again there will be a cuboid of elements which repeats itself in all directions. This need to be as big as possible related to $N^3$. Best case would be just one number which changes according to next functions chosen.

Comment: both user have interest to compute the other user values out of their own. They share as many information they can. I'm looking for a way to make this as hard as possible while still being possible. (Or in case multiple different matrices exists, possible for those with same matrix)

Comment: How important is the cyclic aspect?  If you go upward from $N$ in one dimension do you have to get the number at $1$?  If it is not important, you can just make $m$ huge compared to $N$ and different in each dimension and repeats will be much rarer.  If you make $N$ large enough you will never roll over.

Comment: would be much better if cyclic. There can also be some settle in time, e.g. it starts at 1st element and after N'th element it continues at the 42th element (and to N again, next 42th again,..). If $m$ much greater the amount of different matrices (with size $N$ in each dim) will scale with dimensions. In 'weakening' I wrote that is possible but only up to about $2N$ of those. That would result in $\sqrt[3]{2N}$ for each dimension. This $m$ won't be much bigger than before. ...

Comment: ...Alternative for huge $m$ would be a limited amount of initial values. But if this number is too small the 'matrix-id' can be derived and it would be as hard as the small $m$ version. So for this multiple initial values need to map to the same 'matrix-id'. But how to generate those initial values without exposing the 'matrix-id'?